# Efficient way to add a one row table to another table in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have 2 dfs:

```
A | B
------
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

and

```
C
-
8
```

I want a new df like:

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 2 | 8
3 | 4 | 8
```

Basically that one-row table's value appended to every single row of my original df. Is this possible in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Since `df2` has only one row, if performance is pursued, you can use `lit` to add a column.

```
value_c = df2.collect()[0][0]
df = df1.withColumn('C', F.lit(value_c))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df1.crossJoin(df2)` will create a table with the cartesian product of the 2 tables, which should work in this case.